# Trouble reading created sockets (php)

Tags: php, sockets

I am pretty new to how sockets work. I am in the learning process but there are things I'm not able to understand no matter how much I search.

I made this simple script today:

```
<?php

$ip = getHostByName(getHostName()); //Get IP of machine

$address = $ip;
$port = 34242;

echo "Starting up data processing server...\n";

$socket = socket_create(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

if($socket === false){
    echo "Socket failed to connect.\n";
    exit(1);
}

socket_set_nonblock($socket);

$stopped = false;
$lastread = microtime(true);

while($data = socket_read($socket, 4) && !$stopped){
    $lastread = microtime(true);
}

echo("Closing data processing server, bye!\n");


?>
```

Now when I run it in my console (local host) I get the error:

```
Warning: socket_read(): unable to read from socket [57]: Socket is not connected in /Users/***/Desktop/sockt.php on line 22
```

What am I doing wrong? My intensions are to create a socket which data can be funneled through to give to clients.

Answer (score 0):

you need [socket_connect](http://php.net/socket_connect), to create it is not enough (that's just for setting stuff)

you needed neither `$address` nor `$port`.  ;o)